# WordPress Plugin - Inserting multiple post id within while loop

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I am working with custom-post-type `smart-event` and I have WP_Query with post meta `sevent-date`.There may have been multiple posts in same date.I want to get all the post ids in an array with same date.There might be one, two or more posts.Below is what I am trying to.

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'smart-event',
        'meta_query'=> array(
            'key' => 'sevent_date',
            'value'=> $this_month,
            'type'  => 'date',
            'compare'=> 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    );
$posts = new \WP_Query($args);

$postdateid = array();
if($posts->have_posts()){
    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
        $posts->the_post();

        $date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'sevent_date', true);
        $postdateid[date('d', strtotime($date))] = 
            array( 
                'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)), 
                'id' => array(get_the_ID()), //Here i want to insert multiple ids if available
            ); 
    }wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

But i am getting only one post each day.But there is one date which has two posts.I want to insert all ids in `'id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Checked first array key by `array_key_exists()` then used `array_push()`.Now its working fine.

```
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'smart-event',
            'meta_query'=> array(
                'key' => 'sevent_date',
                'value'=> $this_month,
                'type'  => 'date',
                'compare'=> 'BETWEEN',
            ),
        );
    $posts = new \WP_Query($args);

    $postdateid = array();
    if($posts->have_posts()){
        while ($posts->have_posts()) {
            $posts->the_post();

            $date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'sevent_date', true);
            if(array_key_exists(date('d', strtotime($date)), $postdateid)){
                array_push( $postdateid[date('d', strtotime($date))]['id'], get_the_ID());
            }else{
                $postdateid[date('d', strtotime($date))] = 
                array( 
                    'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)), 
                    'id' => array(
                        get_the_ID()
                    ),
                );
            }
        }wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```